# Is there a good block cipher that supports small block sizes?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which “good” block encryption algorithm has the shortest output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513056/which-good-block-encryption-algorithm-has-the-shortest-output)

I am looking for a block cipher that supports small block sizes,  ideally 16bits in size.  I want to use CMAC mode,  so using a block cipher with OFB mode or a stream cipher is undesirable.  Speed is very important,  and the cipher shouldn't be susceptible to known attacks.  This is a theoretical application and high security isn't required,  however speed is very important.

Does something like this exist?  How close to these specs can I get?

Comment: You're going to have problems with that.  A block cipher is essentially a simple substitution cipher with a key, and has all the vulnerabilities you'd expect from a simple substitution cipher if the block size is small enough that repeated blocks are likely.  That means I rather doubt there's been much work on such blocks, so you'll likely have to roll your own.

Comment: @David Thornley yes,  this is a possible attack over a long period of time.  This attack was used against wep.  In this implementation a key is only used for a short period of time and thus IV's will never be reused.

Comment: Note that CMAC mode creates MACs that are no longer than the cipher block size, so a short block size implies a short MAC.  A 16 bit MAC would appear to be trivially bruteforceable in most applications.

Comment: @caf you are correct. Like i said this is a theoretical application and there will be no real users or real attackers.  It is developing a protocol for a 16bit embedded system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Skipjack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipjack_%28cipher%29) has a 64bit block size and is a [NIST Approved Block Cipher](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/block_ciphers.html#Approved+Algorithms).

Comment: Triple DES has the same block size, is equally approved, and is far more widely implemented. Skipjack is faster though.