# Generate random 10 digit number as part of ID and ensure no duplicates

Tags: sql-server, random

I have a request as part of an application I am working on to generate a UserId with the following criteria:

1. It will have a set 4 digit prefix
2. The next 10 digits will be random
3. A check-digit will be added on the end

Points 1 and 3 are straight-forward, but what would the best way be to generate a 10 digit random number whilst ensuring that it hasn't already been used.

I don't particularly like the idea of choosing one randomly, seeing if it has been taken and then either accepting or trying again.

My other thought was to generate a list of X numbers in advance (X being a number greater than the number of accounts you expect to be created) and just take the next one off the list as the accounts are created.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Lets bring technology into this. If I am using a SQL server database, is there a way I can make the database do this for me? E.g. enforce a unique constraint and get the database to generate the number?

Comment: The only way to be 100% sure there is no other userid with the same random digits is to compare the gernerated to **all** existing users.

Comment: ... which you can do preemptively (as OP suggests) or at creation (as OP dislikes), but you have to do it *sometime*.

Comment: "Lets bring technology into this." Enforcing a unique constraint is easy, just slap a `UNIQUE` index on the column; so you don't need a `SELECT`, just `INSERT` and generate another one if `INSERT` fails. Having the database generate it is a no-go unless you make a stored procedure that will do the same thing, or you use `uniqueidentifier` to make a GUID (which is not 10 digits, but `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513097/60188).

What you need is basically encrypt a sequential ID, thus producing a seemingly random number.

What's especially good about this is that you can do this all client-side, albeit in two consecutive transactions.

Comment: If you change "random" into "seemingly random", this is a good idea; any sufficiently opaque bijective method should do. Finding a bijection that generates precisely 10 digits is a bit of a challenge; OP should judge how tight his #2 requirement is.

Comment: @Amadan You can always pad with zeroes and get precisely 10 digits.

Comment: You are right, in case of a 32-bit output, you will always have up to 10 digits.

Comment: This is also interesting: http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be 100% sure there is no other userid with the same random digits is to compare the gernerated to all existing users, you have to do it *sometime*

**The only possibility is to do this code-side.**

*BUT* you can save the random generated id to the userdatabase and compare this with your new key (in your code)

e.g. `SELECT * FROM xy WHERE userid = 'newuserid'`

If the result is null your key never was generated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anton's answer I found this C# implementation of the skip32 encryption algorithm.

https://github.com/eleven41/Eleven41.Skip32

Using this I can pass in an incrementing database identity integer and get a nice random looking 9/10 digit number from it. So a simple call like

```
int result = cipher.Encrypt(databaseIdentity);
```

will give me the number I want. No need for duplicate checking as each will be unique.